# How to create the transaction before calling components with @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS) annotation?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss-arquillian

I want to use arquillian in my pre-existing system and I am creating the first test.
I call a DAO component to set the test data, so the first command it tries to run is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ...
```

when the code executes the

```
query.executeUpdate()
```

command, I get

> javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an
>   update/delete query

This is my test:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@Transactional
public class MyFirstIT {

//  @Resource
//  private UserTransaction utx;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
//      utx.begin();
    }

    @After
    public void commitTransaction() throws Exception {
//      utx.rollback();
    }

    @Inject
    private MyDAO myDAO;

    @Test
    public void myTest() throws IOException, SolrServerException {
        myDAO.setup();
    }

/* @Deployment ignored for brevity */
}
```

My DAO is defined as such:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
public class MyDAO
```

My dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-transaction-jta</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-persistence-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Alpha6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.10.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.0.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

As you can see, I tried using the arquillian-transaction-jta and @Transactional attribute, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046537/testing-jpa-entity-classes-error-transaction-is-required)

I also tried creating my own transaction, [as described here](https://dwuysan.wordpress.com/2013/03/29/javax-persistence-transactionrequiredexception-using-arquillian/) but none work and I get the same error message.

I think the problem lies on the fact that the DAO has TransactionAttributeTyoe.SUPPORTS annotation. Is there any way I can create the transaction on the test before calling the DAO?

Comment: Try removing the `Transactional` annotation from `MyFirstIT` class.

Comment: I first started without it, I added the @Transaction because of this problem. (same error message)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
```

this means that transaction will be propagated but not created. You should start one before calling the DAO method. It can be:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MyFirstIT {

  @Inject
  private UserTransaction userTransaction;

  @Test
  public void myTest() throws IOException, SolrServerException {
    userTransaction.begin();
    myDAO.setup();
    userTransaction.commit();
  }
}
```

Or you can switch to

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

which starts new transaction inside container. Or use:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
```

which creates only if it didn't come. The latter one is the default (so you can avoid the annotation at all) for @Stateless bean and I'd say is preferrable way in most cases

Comment: I needed to create an EntityManager and then call em.joinTransaction(). Could you please add it to your answer, so I can mark it as answer? No, I cannot change the TransactionAttribute, because this would change production code for testing purposes ;)

Comment: In my environment (Jboss EAP 6.3.3) I do not need this. I just start transaction before calling EJB's and it is automatically propagated

Comment: That is odd... I am using WildFly 8.2. I tried starting the transaction on the @ before method and closing it on the @ After method, but no luck. As soon as I used the joinTransaction, it worked...

Comment: Probably @ Before and @ After are inappropriate places for that. You should do it in @ Test method (I mean starting and commiting a transaction) as pointed out in my code. Anyway if your solution works for you perhaps it is not a big deal which one to use