# EntityManager.contains - returns false in same transaction

Tags: java, transactions, entitymanager, jta, java-ee-7

I'm struggling to understand how the `EntityManager.contains` method works, and other answers in SO didn't help me.

This is the situation:

I call `persist(enity)` and `contains(entity)` in the same transaction

```
@Test
@Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRED)
public void testContains() {
    Band band = new Band();
    // populating band...

    // bandDao is an `@Inject`ed in the class
    bandDao.save(band);
    assertThat(bandDao.contains(band), is(true));
}
```

The `BandDao` `contains` and `save` methods are implemented as follows

```
public class BandDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    ...

    @Transactional(value = TxType.REQUIRED)
    public void save(Band band) {
        em.persist(band);
    }

    public boolean contains(Band band) {
        return em.contains(band);
    }
}
```

Only `save` is marked as `@Transactional`; but, if I didn't get it wrong, the transaction should be propagated from the caller.

Running the test, it fails as it is expecting a `true`, but it receives a `false`.

I'm running these tests with `Arquillian` in a `Wildfly 10` remote container. All other tests in the suite (persisting, updating, retrieving entities) succeed, the only one that fails is the one about the `contains` method.

Can anyone explain  me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have `equals` and `hashcode` for `Band` been overridden?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko `equals` is, `hashCode` is not

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I tried to add the `hashCode` implementation as well (using `Apache`'s `HashCodeBuilder`), but it didn't solve.

Comment: yes, `hashcode` doesn't solve a problem, that's just a good style to override them together

Comment: looks like the problem has nothing to do with transaction management, but with `Arquillian` itself. If I remove the `@Transactional` annotation from the `BandDao.save` method it fails because no transaction is defined at the moment the entity is persisted. Means that, after all, I'm not executing the `persist` and the `contains` methods in the same transaction, I think.

Answer (score 1):

At the end, the problem is not related to transaction management but to Arquillian itself which didn't manage the `@Transactional` annotation on the test classes.

See: [Testing jpa entity classes - error Transaction is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046537/testing-jpa-entity-classes-error-transaction-is-required/)